# How to dynamically load classes and libraries from different project in runtime

Tags: java, xml, dynamic, classloader, dynamic-loading

I have solution split into 2 projects:

- The *independent* project contains interface `ExampleInf` and declares some services needed for the application. Those services are provided by the third party API ([Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) client API). This project contains GUI components and other application logic but does not link third party libraries that provide services declared by `ExampleInf`. There is no class implementing `ExampleInf` in this project.
- The *dependent* project that contains links to third party libraries. This project contains class `ExampleImpl` that encapsulates third party API and implements `ExampleInf`.

In the *independent* project there is class (let's call it class `A`) that consumes (uses) services declared by `ExampleInf`. Because the *independent* does not link the *dependent* project, in order to use `ExampleInf` it needs to load its implementation `ExampleImpl` dynamically in runtime. Also it needs to dynamically load all the third party libraries required by `ExampleImpl`.

Currently this is done by a bunch of constants (`public static final String` attributes) that contain paths to *dependent* project where dynamically loaded resources are located and a lot of messy `ClassLoader` code. I do not consider this to be a good solution. Is there any pattern, best practice or common way how this can be done? What would you recommend in your experience?

This pattern reminds me a bit of dependency injection in Java EE. At least I think it is good idea to externalize the locations of classes and libraries (.jar-s) that need to be loaded dynamically to XML and then load them all in cycle instead of calling `ClassLoader.loadClass` separately for each constant. Is there any nice clean way how to load XML in the same package and load classes and jars specified by that XML? Code example would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ServiceLoader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html) utility to do this (this is how many of the jdk services are loaded, e.g. xml libraries and modern jdbc driver libraries).  If the dependent project is part of the classpath at startup, then you are good to go (assuming it is setup correctly).  otherwise, you would need to load the dependent project in a nested classloader and pass that to the `load(Class,ClassLoader)` method (or set the classloader as the current context classloader before calling `load(Class)`).

Comment: The *dependent* project is not part of classpath of the *independent* project at startup nor are the .jars that contain Hadoop client API (third party library). Would you mind adding short code sample on how to load project in a nested `ClassLoader` and how how the META-INF/services may look like? Except of loading some JDBC drivers I have no experience with class loading.

Comment: @drasto - the javaodoc i linked to details how to setup the META-INF/services and there are many, many answers on this website about setting up nested classloaders, also here https://www.google.com/search?q=java+tutorial+urlclassloader.